# parallax with fading effect background images?

Tags: jquery, html, css

To started building single page website with parallax effect, parallax effect is new for me, how can code same like the below reference website https://www.fitbit.com/in/charge.

Please assist to achieve the task.

Answer (score 1):

check out this [fullpage plugin](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

The key point of parallax effect is monitor "scrolltop" of window. You can also emplement your parallax page without any third party lib

```
   var $win = $(window);
   $win.on('scroll',function(){
       var top = $win.scrollTop();
       if(top > ... &&　top < ...){
          //do something
       }else if(top > ... && top < ...){
          // do something else
       }

   })
```

and your given reference site is implement in this way:

a. create two layers, a normal one(part A) and a fixed positioned one(part B). and part A is divided into three section(section A, section B, section C);
         partA:
             section A,
             section B(height = $(window).height() * 4),
             section C
         partB:
             height = $(window).height(), display:none;

b. monitoring $(window).scrollTop(), when user scroll DOWN $(window).height() - sectionA.height, you display partB.

c. since you just using a fixed positioned layer cover partA, user can still scrolling down. and you can do certain things according to $(window).scrollTop();

d. when $(window).scrollTop > sectionA.height + sectionB.height - $(window).height. Hide partB and user will only see sectionC.

BTW, if you try to implement parallax effect by yourself, don't forget to handle "window.resize" event since once the window resizing, everything changes.

Comment: your given fullpage plugin. is for smooth scrolling purpose, comparing to my reference site https://www.fitbit.com/in/charge fully different..can you explaining little bit more...please

Comment: hope the new edition could explain better. Actually ,I used to write a webpage like your given example. If you still can not understand I could give you my source code as example.